# AcceptedFileType in php-dropzone does'nt work

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

I have changed the accepted file type in form-dropzone.min.js and dropzone.in.js files, to image/* and application/pdf(also tried .jpeg, .png, .jpg etc), but still all types of files are accepted. I am looking at validating the file type something similar to this

[image]

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: Dropzone.options.myDropzone={
    acceptedFiles: " image/* ",

Comment: You wrote that you changed "form-dropzone.min.js and dropzone.in.js". Are that files you created or is that the code from dropzone.js?

Comment: i changed acceptedFiles in "form-dropzone.min.js and dropzone.in.js ...still does'nt work